# Problem on integration by parts in the heat equation

Tags: integration, heat-equation

I have the given heat equation problem I struggle to solve:

$$u_t-3u_{xx}=0\\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(3,t)=0\\
u(x,0)=4\cos3\pi x$$

Here we have Neumann condition on x, and $L=3$, so we can readily make the ansatz $$u(x,t)=\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}\ u(t)$$.

Solving for $u(t)$:

$$u_{xx}=-\bigg(\frac{n\pi}{3}\bigg)^2\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}\ u(t), \\ u_t=\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}u_t$$ Insert in the PDE and solve:

$$\cos\frac{n\pi}{3}u_t+\bigg(\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)^2\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}u(t)=0$$

$$u_t+\bigg(\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)^2 u=0$$

$$\frac{u_t}{u}=-\bigg(\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)^2 $$

$$u(t)=Ce^{-(\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{3}})^2t} $$

Now the solution is:

$$u(x,t)=C\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}e^{(-\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{3}})^2t}$$

Use the initial condition to find C, as it is a Fourier coefficient:

$$\alpha_k=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x)\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}dx$$

where $f(x)=4\cos3\pi x$, so we have to solve the integral by parts:

$$\alpha_k=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x)\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}dx=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^34\cos3\pi x\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx$$

but this gives:

$$\frac{8}{3}\int_0^3 \cos3\pi x\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx=\frac{8}{3}\frac{3}{n\pi}\cos3\pi x\sin\frac{n\pi}{3}x\bigg|_0^3+\frac{8}{3}\frac{9\pi}{n\pi}\int_0^3\sin3\pi x\sin\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx$$

The first term on the RHS is zero, and the second is:

$$\frac{8}{3}\frac{9}{n}\int_0^3\sin3\pi x\sin\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx=0-\frac{8}{3}\frac{9}{n}\int_0^3\cos3\pi x\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx$$.

Set this equal to the top LHS:

$$\frac{8}{3}\int_0^3\cos3\pi x\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx=-\frac{8}{3}\frac{9}{n}\int_0^3\cos3\pi x\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx$$

But this has no solution!

However, Mathematica solves this integration by parts nicely and gets a feasible result. So what went wrong here?

Comment: Why mess with integrals to get the coefficents, when you can simply read off $n$ and the corresponding $C_n$ directly from the inititial condition? (After all, there's just one single term in the Fourier series!)

Comment: @HansLundmark I heard about this method you mention, apparently, it is the simplest form. But can you form an answer to this, I have no idea how to do it!

Comment: According to Hans comment, all integrals except for $n=9$ should be equal to zero. I believe there is sign error in $$\frac{8}{3}\frac{9}{n}\int_0^3\sin3\pi x\sin\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx=0-\frac{8}{3}\frac{9}{n}\int_0^3\cos3\pi x\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx$$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu so how do you "read" off the result, and what is the result? Can you form an answer? I give you 20 point for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer is given in comments of Hans and gpmath, so I'll just show error in original post.
$$\alpha_n=\frac{8}{3}\frac{9}{n}\int_0^3\sin3\pi x\sin\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx$$
Using integration by parts again one can get
$$\alpha_n=\left.-\frac8{3}\frac9{n}\frac3{n\pi}\sin(3\pi x)\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}\right|_0^3+\frac8{3}\frac9{n}\frac9{n}\int_0^3\cos(3\pi x)\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}dx=\frac{81}{n^2}\alpha_n$$
Then $\alpha_n=0$ or $81=n^2$, then $u$ contains only one non-zero term corresponding to $n=9$

---

General solution is $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n \cos \frac{n\pi x}{3} \exp \left(\mathbf{-} \left(\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2 t\right)$$

Putting general solution in initial condition gives $$4\cos 3\pi x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n \cos \frac{n\pi x}{3}$$ $\alpha_n$ is coefficient of Fourier expansion of $u(x,0)=4\cos 3\pi x$ corresponding to term $\cos \frac{n\pi x}{3}$. However $\cos 3\pi x$ is already of type $\cos \frac{n\pi x}{3}$ at $n=9$. Then Fourier expansion of $u(x,0)$ contains only one non-zero term. $4\cos 3\pi x = 4 \cos \frac{9\pi x}{3}$, then $\alpha_9=4$ and all other $\alpha_n$ are zero.

Comment: I think I get it. You equalize the integral like I did in the OP (without that errror) and then you squareroot $81/n^2$ from the result and obtain n=9. Isn't that value of n related to the 3 in $$u(x,0)=4\cos 3\pi x?$$

Comment: So $C=4$ since $u(x,0)=4\cdot \cos 3\pi x$ ?

Comment: Yes, and $n=9$ because $\frac{n\pi x}{3}=3\pi x$

Comment: You confirmed this by actually taking the integral, which I follow. But what did Hans mean, that you can get this without taking the integral? What is the rule?

Comment: $u(x,0)=4\cos 3\pi x$ is already Fourier expansion of $u(x,0)$

Comment: Also you've lost minus in exponent: $u(x,y)=C \cos \frac{n\pi x}{3} \exp \left(\mathbf{-} \left(\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2 t\right)$

Comment: Yes, that was a silly typo

Answer (score 1):

It's just easier. You know that $$u(x,0)=4\cos 3\pi x,$$ so just put $t=0$ in your solution, that is, $n=9$ and $C=4$.

Comment: So the solution is with 
$$u(x,t)=C\cos\frac{n\pi x}{3}e^{(\frac{n\pi}{\sqrt{3}})^2t}=4\cos 4\pi xe^{(\frac{12\pi}{\sqrt{3}})^2t}$$ ?  No sum and expansion as Fourier series?

Comment: Correct result is: $u(x,t)=4 e^{-27 \pi ^2 t} \cos (3 \pi  x)$

Comment: Guillermo: $n=9$ not 12.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz: It *is* a Fourier series, it's just that all Fourier coefficients except one are equal to zero.

Comment: @HansLundmark  perhaps you can correct everything here?There are three results here.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz: You can easily verify for yourself whether a proposed solution is correct or not by simply checking whether it satisfies the PDE and the additional conditions. (That's a good skill to have on the exam!)

Comment: I know, but I don't see the rationale behind this. Ivans suggestion is interesting, but what does it mean that the $\alpha_k=\frac{81}{n^2}\alpha_k$? It makes no sense. This is the same as saying that $1=\frac{81}{n^2}$ which has no meaning. What is the right answer?

Comment: $\alpha_n=\frac{81}{n^2}\alpha_n \Rightarrow \alpha_n=0 \lor n=9$, then the only non-zero $\alpha_n$ is $\alpha_9$. Double using of integration by parts does not give the value of $\alpha_9$ because it leads to $\alpha_9=\alpha_9$